# How to use sequelize(mysql) to count datas with angularjs + nodejs?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have three tables in **mysql**

1. Contact
2. Group
3. ContactGroup

Here is my table structure:

```
var Contact = sequelize.define('contact', {
    gsm: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        unique: true,
        required: true
    },
    firstName: Sequelize.STRING,
    lastName: Sequelize.STRING,
    street: Sequelize.STRING,
    city: Sequelize.STRING,
    region: Sequelize.STRING,
    postcode: Sequelize.STRING,
    dob: Sequelize.DATE,
    email: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        unique: true,
        defaultValue: true
    },
    company: Sequelize.STRING,
    url: Sequelize.STRING,
    country: Sequelize.STRING,
    data1: Sequelize.STRING,
    data2: Sequelize.STRING,
    data3: Sequelize.STRING,
    //  resetPasswordToken: Sequelize.STRING,
    //  resetPasswordExpires: Sequelize.DATE,
    //  lastLoggedIn: Sequelize.DATE
})


var Group = sequelize.define('group', {
    groupname: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        unique: true,
        required: true
    },
})

var ContactGroup = sequelize.define('contactgroup', {
    /* Empty */
})

ContactGroup.belongsTo(Contact, {
    onDelete: 'CASCADE'
});
ContactGroup.belongsTo(Group, {
    onDelete: 'CASCADE'
});

Group.hasMany(ContactGroup, {
    onDelete: 'CASCADE'
});
```

**My Scenario:**
I have two UI in my project:

1.Contact
2.Group

**STEP 1:** First User can add group,then user will go to create new contact, this contact may contain many groups or with no groups **(groups data come as dropdown from the group table, which user done this operation on STEP 1**)

**For example-real-time scenario:**

I am the User who enters into application,

**Step 1:** I will add new group called **'angulargroup'**.

**Step 2:** I will add my details in contact and select **angulargroup** in dropdown, so i can belong to angulargroup
Now user interaction over.

Now i got contact id and group id, i stored this group id and contact id in my table called **ContactGroup** which looks like:

[image]

So finally help me to show counts of groups:

I added only one contact in **angulargroup**, so i want to display **CONTACT COUNT** as 1 in the below image:

[image]

If i added two **contacts** in **angulargroup** in the place of contactcount i want to show contactcount as **2**

my api.js code:

```
exports.getNewGroup = function(req, res) {
    Group.findAndCountAll({
        attributes: ['id', [sequelize.fn('COUNT', sequelize.col('contactgroups.groupId')),
            'contactCount'
        ]],
        include: [{
            model: ContactGroup,
        }]
    }).then(function(data) {
        return res.status(200).send(data);
    }).catch(function(err) {
        return res.status(400).send(err.message);
    });
};
```

and now how to display this in UI:

```
table.table
 tr
  th(style='display : none;') S.no
  th Name
  th Contacts Count
 tr(ng-repeat='group in groups | filter:test')
  td(style='display : none;') {{$index+1}}
  td {{group.groupname}}  
  td {{group.contactId}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got it:

Here is the answer:

my api.js:

```
exports.getNewGroup = function (req, res) {
    Group.findAll({
        attributes: {
            include: [
                [sequelize.fn('COUNT', sequelize.col('contactgroups.groupId')), 'contactsCount']
            ],
        },
        include: [{
            model: ContactGroup,
            attributes: [],
        }],
        group: ['Group.id'],
        raw: true
    }).then(function (data) {
        return res.status(200).send(data);
    }).catch(function (err) {
        return res.status(400).send(err.message);
    });
};
```